# Mocking a File object in NestJs unit test with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, file-upload, nestjs, multer, type-assertion

I recently started working with Nest.js and its built-in unit testing library Jest, while on a task to upload a .CSV file and perform some operations on it, I decided to also unit test the endpoint and this required me to mock the CSV file object, which I did as thus

```
const mockFile = {
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'TradeHistory.csv',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/csv',
  buffer: Buffer.from(__dirname + '/../../TradeHistory.csv', 'utf8'),
  size: 51828,
}
```

I quickly ran into these issues;

- For file upload, I was using the @UseInterceptors() and @UploadedFile()
- which takes a type of **file: Express.Multer.File**
- Which won't accept my mocked file **object** type as an argument

So I searched for a way to convert the mocked file into a type **Express.Multer.File**
and after a while what worked for me turned out to be embarrassingly simple and straightforward as using the type assertion **as** keyword to cast the file object **Express.Multer.File**

```
const mockFile = {
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'TradeHistory.csv',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/csv',
  buffer: Buffer.from(__dirname + '/../../TradeHistory.csv', 'utf8'),
  size: 51828,
} as Express.Multer.File
```

Other ways might exist, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Great. Came across your posting. Used it in my unit test mocking Multer file. Saved my day!

Comment: Yes, this looks like a very valid way of doing it, thanks for sharing!